# Jersey JAX-RS and AWS SDK: Tomcat won't start

Tags: java, amazon-s3, jersey, jax-rs

I'm working on a java web application that utilizes the Jersey JAX-RS implementation for building RESTful Services.  All has been well until I added the Amazon Web Services jars to my WEB-INF/lib folder.  I'd like to store some data in Amazon S3, but it seems the AWS SDK and Jersey don't play nicely together.  With both sets of jars in my lib folder Tomcat won't start.  If I remove the jersey-servlet.jar, Tomcat starts, but of course leaves my services broken.  I'm using Jersey v1.2 and AWS SDK 1.3.20.

Has anybody else seen this same behavior?

Thanks

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readFields(ClassParser.java:223)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:126)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2066)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1942)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1908)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1893)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1296)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:855)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:346)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
... 8 more
Oct 2, 2012 12:36:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component      [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
```

Comment: can you please update Jersey to version 1.14? And maybe try to dig more about that OOM (I don't see any Jersey stuff in your stacktrace)

Comment: This is a little bit embarrassing but it turns out all I needed to do was allocate more space to the JVM :(

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve this.  Turns out it was as simple as allocating more space to the JVM.